# How to access Elasticsearch with Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-functions, gateway, azure-function-app

I have an Elasticsearch cluster that I need to access using an Azure Functions App. The current way to access it is via an IP whitelist. I've created my consumption plan Azure Functions and noticed that the IP address kept changing and after further research found that I'd need to whitelist the whole Azure Cloud which is not a secure option in our case. So I've upgraded Azure Functions to Premium plan and thus the VNet Integration appeared in the app settings allowing me to create a Virtual Network and a static Outbound IP Address.

Now it is working.

But since I'm using the Premium plan and the other mentioned services, the cost went up.

I've experimented with Azure Data Factory in the past and there was an option to install a local Integration Runtime so when ADF was accessing Elasticsearch via the Local Integration Runtime, it worked. Is there something similar I can use with Azure Functions? Like a Data Gateway I can install on a local server that is already whitelisted on Elasticsearch and all I'd need to do is connect from Azure Functions through it?

I guess the ideal scenario I'm looking for is to be able to use a Consumption Plan on Azure Functions.

Kind Regards,
Andrei

Comment: if Premium Functions is too expensive, have you looked at AppServicePlan-Functions? they also provide VNet integration

Comment: Hi. Yes in the end I think we'll use a Standard (S1) AppServicePlan for our Function Apps.

Comment: Could you please post an answer in below area for other communities reference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this one, in the end, I've used a Standard AppSevicePlan (S1) (costs $74|£51/month or about $2.5|£1.7/day). I've had to create a static Outbound IP, a NAT Gateway (which costs about another $30|£23/month or $1|£.77/day) and a VNET.
The tutorial can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-nat-gateway

Another option that I've considered to reduce cost was to use a Hybrid Connection which would install a sort of gateway to a local server to which Azure Functions would connect first before reaching the ES endpoint...that would eliminate the need for the Outbound IP, NAT Gateway and VNET (so $30 less per month) but would still require at least an S1...so no option on consumption-based, and I don't know if there is any charge associated with this. However, we didn't go with this option as we want to eliminate any local dependencies (e.g. if the server where the gateway is running would shut down).

To sum up, use an S1, follow the tutorial mentioned above and should cost about $104|£74/month